# Make a search function in Google Sheets that retrieves row numbers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working on a sheet for the game No man's sky and would like some help with creating a search function since the normal filter function do not work on vertically merged cells.
In R1 i will put in the word/words to search for.
In R2 the function script will be placed and the search result displayed.
The search result i want are what row in the range (R4:R) the word i am searching for exists. so if the word i am searching for in R1 is Copper, and the word is listed on row 5 8 16 then i want 5, 8, 16, to show up in R2. i would like it if the function was also able to work even if the search words are contained inside dropdowns or if i decide to add a dropdown to the input cell R1.

I have gone through the different functions listed in the function list for Google Sheets but have not ben able to combine the right once to make it work. i am not fluent in JavaScript which is probably why i am finding it hard to make a working script for this.

Comment: please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result. You can [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform).

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UY4iOSQU_qNK98Ty3TqaHNnp7wB8rPFg00mx-09be8Q/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this in `Cell R2`:

```
=join(", ",ifna(filter(row(R4:R),xmatch(R4:R,R1))))
```

Comment: nope did not work. you can test your formula by yourself on this sample sheet i made out of my real one https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UY4iOSQU_qNK98Ty3TqaHNnp7wB8rPFg00mx-09be8Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried the formula in `Cell R2` of your sample sheet and What error are you seeing exactly?

Comment: This is a locale issue. If your locale = "Sweden", then try `=join(", ";ifna(filter(row(R4:R);xmatch(R4:R;R1))))`. Refer Cell T2 of your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula in Cell R2:

`=iferror(arrayformula(join(",",query({R4:R,row(R4:R)},"select Col2  where Col1 is not null and Col1 contains '"&$R1&"'"))),"No Match")`

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: snapshot]

Comment: after putting in your formula into R2 it first just gave me parse error as and i solved it by exchanging all the , to ; . but now it just says no match when i put in a word into R1so i guess it is not working as intended. also the sample is not how i intended it to be either as i need the result to be displayed in R2 so in the same cell as the formula is.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w0S9.png

Comment: Sigh. I hate those black screens with a passion; but you could also have included your formula in your comment as text.  Rant over ;) I think you have `&$R2&""` where it should be `&$R2&"'"`. i.e. you're missing the single quote between the double quotes. If that doesn't help, _please_ (I'm begging) include a spreadsheet cause your search term might have a trailing space, or there might be a trailing space in the data, or or or...

Comment: I already did share a link to a sample sheet i did put together yesterday. as i saw ztiaa asked for it in their comment at the top. here is the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UY4iOSQU_qNK98Ty3TqaHNnp7wB8rPFg00mx-09be8Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I inserted the formula answer into cell R2 and it worked - no parse error, no "Mismatch". Refer cell S2 of your spreadsheet for proof example. The main problem is that you somehow changed the reference cell for the search term - this needs to be $R1 (or $R$1). You have the search term looking in $R2.

Comment: okay now it works thanks. Buuut now i also see that your formula do not seem to like when i apply it to a column like Q which has merged cells as it then sees the empty cells that has ben merged as a search result... also  sort of need it to not see Activated Copper as a search result if i only search for copper in R column. I need the search function to be picky about what qualifies as a valid search result...

Comment: Also.. i realize that further on when i list more systems and planets, going through the rows listed by your function will become impractical and quite difficult... i think i will neeed the search function to somehow highlight by changing either format or text or fill color of the cell or rows that has ben listed and/or make the row numbers listed act as webpage navigation shortcuts so when i click one then my sheet will auto scroll down to that row for me..

Comment: something like this could probably be implemented into the search function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45888328/changing-background-color-of-specific-cell-on-google-sheet to make it highlight the cell the search result refers to

Comment: I just found a formula that sort of is almost just what  i need. i think you might be able to easily be able to implement it into the search formula so the sheet auto scrolls down to the selected result row (yes i tested it on my P column) =IF(LEN(P1)<2;"None";FILTER(HYPERLINK("#gid=0&range=P"&ROW(P4:P);P4:P);LEFT(P4:P;LEN(P1))=P1))

Comment: `merged cells`, `Activated Copper`, `search function to somehow highlight`, `something like this could probably be implemented`, `I just found a formula that sort of is almost just what i need.` I (and probably @rockinfreakshow) recognised some of these issues.  But... you asked a specific question, provided some specific data, and received not one but two good answers. With respect, these additional issues should be raised as new questions. On a tangent, please consider `accepting` one of these answers (I personally favour rockinfreakshow's  answer).